# Change "Unidentified networks" to "private" in powershell

Tags: windows, networking, powershell, group-policy

I would like to change the connection type for "Unidentified" networks to Private in Windows using Powershell. Ideally this should work in Win 8 and 10.

An alternative solution would be to make windows identify this network and then I can set the location to private. It is a VirtualBox host only network with a Linux host.

I can use the UI to do this with the following steps:

- Open Group policy editor eg (start -> gpedit.msc)
- Computer Configuration -> Windows Settings -> Security Settings -> Network List Manager Policies
- Where it says "Unidentified Networks", Right click -> Properties
- Change "Location type" to Private

I have googled and tried:

```
$networkListManager = [Activator]::CreateInstance([Type]::GetTypeFromCLSID([Guid]"{DCB00C01-570F-4A9B-8D69-199FDBA5723B}"))
$connections = $networkListManager.GetNetworkConnections()

$connections |foreach {
    $_.GetNetwork().SetCategory(1)
}
```

but this does not survive a reboot.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote [a script](https://github.com/hahndorf/hacops/blob/master/Set-NetworkProfileCategory.ps1) last year and put it on GitHub. It does exactly what you want:

```
Set-NetworkProfileCategory.ps1 -Name 'Unidentified network' -private
```

I haven't tested it for a while, but you can try.

Comment: Thanks very much. I had a quick look and it didn't work out of the box for the unidentified network. I can't remember what the error was. Next week when I'm back I'll try and track down the issue. I got as far as the 'unidentified network' wasn't in that registry path yet it was shown by the powershell command.